# Embedded Crystal variables in templating

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

I’m new to Crystal (and never really used ruby) so apologies for the ignorance here! I've looked at the [ecr docs](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.4/ECR.html) but can't seem to find an answer there.

I’m looking at using Embedded Crystal for dynamic templates in [Kemal](http://kemalcr.com/). Can I confirm - can templates only render variables that are available in the scope of the call, or can one make method/function calls from within the template itself? I.E. is there any possibility/risk of being able to execute “malicious” crystal code from within a template (in this case malicious refers to I/O  or file access etc)?

To take an example from the Kemal docs:

```
get "/:name" do |env|
  name = env.params.url["name"]
  render "src/views/hello.ecr"
end
```

In the view `hello.ecr` - is `name` the only item that will be available in the template, or could one call `File.delete("./foo")`from within the template for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template is compiled into Crystal code, you can write any kind of code in there, like `File.delete("./foo")`, for example if you write `<% File.delete("./foo") %>` inside of your template.

If your worry is that `name` will contain code and that will somehow get executed, then don't worry, that's not going to happen. Dynamic runtime code execution in Crystal is not possible, so there's no way someone will inject malicious code into your templates.

Comment: Thank you @asterite for your quick response.  My concern is not so much that the variables would contain code, rather I was looking for a solution to parse externally provided html templates (the contents of which I may/will not know in advance) and would like to avoid any possibility of execution of code beyond basic variables and control structures (if, else, unless etc.) if possible.

Comment: [This snippet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crystal-lang/jX_dRFSdh78) , although quite old, details what I was looking for: 


"A simpler solution would be to have a template system where you can't execute arbitrary code. You could have if, else, a kind of for for iterating and that's it. Then at runtime you would interpret that template, I guess. You would pass an object to that template. It can be a hash containing the values. Or maybe a struct..."


I appreciate this would require runtime interpretation, but this would suffice for this particular case. Any ideas?

Comment: @corkington with ECR there's absolutely no way to execute arbitrary code, because runtime execution of arbitrary code is impossible in Crystal

Comment: Apologies I wasn’t very clear in my previous comment. After some investigation, what I really was looking for was a templating engine akin to Liquid. Handily, [A port to crystal](https://github.com/TechMagister/liquid.cr) appears to have been made recently, which looks as though it offers the functionality I require.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what you mean. The users of your application will provide the templates and you are not in control of them? In that case, neither ECR nor Liquid (at least not that port) will be useful, because they both compile templates to Crystal code at compile-time. We are still missing a template engine that does things at runtime.

Comment: Yes that is precisely the use case. Ok, thanks for the heads up, that clarifies the situation.

Comment: You can take a look at [Crinja](https://github.com/straight-shoota/crinja), an implementation of the Jinja2 template engine in Crystal. It parses templates at runtime and can only execute code that is explicitly exposed to the engine (like filters, functions and tags).